# Material UI: Remove up/down arrow dials from TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this TextField in Material UI:

```
<TextField
      id="contact phone number"
      label="Contact phone number"
      type="number"
      value={this.state.contactPhoneNumber}
      onChange={this.handleChange('contactPhoneNumber')}
      placeholder="Contact phone number"
      margin="normal"
/>
```

It looks like this:
[image]

How would I remove the up and down arrow dials from the TextField?

Comment: Like Allen G said, `type="tel"` seems to work great https://jsfiddle.net/w5246Lzd/1/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the [TextField docs](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/), the `type` prop accepts valid HTML input types. I believe the reason the up and down arrows are present is because you specified `number` as the type.

Try `type="tel"` instead, as it seems to be the standard input type for phone numbers.

Here is a [reference to the tel type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel) and why it's a good idea to use it. Note that if the current browser doesn't support it, it will fall back to being a regular text field.

Comment: If you can share a way to format the number like a telephone number I'll blow you more points

Comment: This solution worked for me, one thing I am wondering is how I can get back the number data type validation I had with type="number"?

Comment: I've downvoted because whilst this is a quick fix, it removes all validation that the contents be a valid float or integer, meaning you have more work to do in your form validation. The removal of the arrows via css (other answers) would retain the numeric constraint whilst still fixing the problem.

Answer (score 48):

You can try css approach for that.

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Works For me. If you don't want to affect all input then you can add class to TextField and use like this:
.mui-number-field {
        input::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
        input::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
            -webkit-appearance: none; 
            margin: 0; 
        }
    }

Answer (score 27):

In React `v 17.0.2` and Material-UI `v 4.11.4`, this works for me:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  input: {
    '& input[type=number]': {
        '-moz-appearance': 'textfield'
    },
    '& input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button': {
        '-webkit-appearance': 'none',
        margin: 0
    },
    '& input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button': {
        '-webkit-appearance': 'none',
        margin: 0
    }
  },
});

export default function MyComponent() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <TextField className={classes.input} />;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, still working fine

Answer (score 19):

For Material UI version 5

```js
const Input = styled(MuiInput)(({ theme }) => ({
  "& input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, & input::-webkit-inner-spin-button": {
    display: "none",
  },
  "& input[type=number]": {
    MozAppearance: "textfield",
  },
}));
```

And then use it as

```js
<Input 
      id="contact phone number"
      label="Contact phone number"
      type="number"
      value={this.state.contactPhoneNumber}
      onChange={this.handleChange('contactPhoneNumber')}
      placeholder="Contact phone number"
      margin="normal"
/>
```

Comment: For those whose TypeScript complains about MuiInput not being found, just put TextField instead of MuiInput. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer using mui v5

Answer (score 17):

This works for me (css help: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp)

```
input: {
    background: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    border: `1px solid white`,
    flex: 1,
    padding: '8px',
    '&[type=number]': {
      '-moz-appearance': 'textfield',
    },
    '&::-webkit-outer-spin-button': {
      '-webkit-appearance': 'none',
      margin: 0,
    },
    '&::-webkit-inner-spin-button': {
      '-webkit-appearance': 'none',
      margin: 0,
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 6):

Material-Ui v5 beta

```
    MuiInput: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          '& input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, & input::-webkit-inner-spin-button':
            {
              display: 'none',
            },
          '& input[type=number]': {
            MozAppearance: 'textfield',
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

Comment: Replacing MuiInput with MuiTextField in your answer worked for me as I am using TextField from MUI.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To add to the existing answers, here is a way of removing the up/down arrow icons using the sx prop (MUI 5):

```
<TextField
 sx={{
 "& input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, & input::-webkit-inner-spin-button": {
                          display: "none",
                        },
"& input[type=number]": {
                          MozAppearance: "textfield",
                        },
}}
type="number"
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

The question is old but maybe this answer may help those who are still seeking a valid answer.

If you use an outlined textfield you can create a class like,

```
textfieldClass: {
'& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': {
  '&::-webkit-outer-spin-button, &::-webkit-inner-spin-button': {
    '-webkit-appearance': 'none',
},
}
```

},

If you use underlined textfield;

```
textfieldClass: {
 '& .MuiInput-input': {
  '&::-webkit-outer-spin-button, &::-webkit-inner-spin-button': {
    '-webkit-appearance': 'none',
  },
 }
},
```

then you can use it in TextField like:

```
<TextField
  className={classes.textfieldClass}
  id="contact phone number"
  label="Contact phone number"
  type="number"
  value={this.state.contactPhoneNumber}
  onChange={this.handleChange('contactPhoneNumber')}
  placeholder="Contact phone number"
  margin="normal"
```

/>

Answer (score 1):

In my case, if I set it as `type=tel` then, I will be able to type letters also inside the field which I do not want it. Instead, I did the below one and it worked for me

```
 const StyledInput= styled(OutlinedInput)`
  input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
  input[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    display: none;
  }`;

 <StyledInput
                type="number"
                inputProps={{ min: 0 }}
                onChange={event => {
                   ...
                }}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type="number" to type="tel"

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me this way:

```
const stylesCSS = {
    input: {
      "& input[type=number]": {
        MozAppearance: "textfield",
      },
      "& input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button": {
        WebkitAppearance: "none",
        margin: 0,
      },
      "& input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button": {
        WebkitAppearance: "none",
        margin: 0,
      },
}


<TextField
  label={user === "freelancer" ? "CPF" : "CNPJ"}
  onChange={(e) => setDocumento(e.target.value)}
  required
  variant="outlined"
  color="primary"
  type="number"
  sx={{ mb: 3, ...stylesCSS.input }}
  value={documento}
  error={documentoError}
  fullWidth
  placeholder="Insira sem os pontos e traços"
/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Change `TextField` attribute `type` from `number` to `tel`

For Example:

```
<TextField label="Phone No" type="number" required />
```

To

```
<TextField label="Phone No" type="tel" required />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).