# How to remove up and down arrow in MUI number field?

Tags: css, material-ui

I want to remove the up and down arrow when using the MUI number field. I'm using **version 5.3.0**. Is it possible in **sx** prop?

[image]

[The sx prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/)

```
<TextField
  sx={{...}}
  id="outlined-number"
  label="Number"
  type="number"     
/>
```

Comment: It's possible, although not through the `sx` prop, as you need to style _pseudo-elements_ representing the buttons. And it's a [hack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-inner-spin-button). You can check this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396280/customizing-increment-arrows-on-input-of-type-number-using-css) for details. A simple working example can be found in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/input-number-no-spinners-k33me)

Comment: thanks, @tromgy sandbox code is working.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, the type prop accepts valid HTML input types. I believe the reason the up and down arrows are present is because you specified number as the type.

Try `type="tel"` instead, as it seems to be the standard input type for phone numbers.

[Here is a reference to the tel type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel) and why it's a good idea to use it. Note that if the current browser doesn't support it, it will fall back to being a regular text field

I found this answer here:
[How to remove the up and down arrow from a mui number field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823182/material-ui-remove-up-down-arrow-dials-from-textview/50824080)

Comment: you cannot input a decimal number if change to 'tel', not a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

First add className to NumberField component

```js
   <NumberField className="no-spinners" />
```

This works for me. (The CSS Approach)

```css
   .no-spinners input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
   .no-spinners input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: textfield;
        margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom styling:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  customNumberField: {
    '& input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, & input::-webkit-inner-spin-button': {
      '-webkit-appearance': 'none',
      margin: 0,
    },
    '& input[type="number"]': {
      '-moz-appearance': 'textfield',
    },
  },
});

function MyComponent() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TextField
      className={classes.customNumberField}
      label="Number"
      type="number"
      // other props
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I've hit upon this recently and yes, it's possible using the sx prop:

```
<TextField
 sx={{
 "& input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, & input::-webkit-inner-spin-button": {
                          display: "none",
                        },
"& input[type=number]": {
                          MozAppearance: "textfield",
                        },
}}
id="outlined-number"
label="Number"
type="number" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Below are the styles to hide the arrows

Mui component

```
<OutlinedInput onFocus={handleInputFocus}/>

  input[type='number'] {
 -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
const handleInputFocus = (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
e.target.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
};
```

Script to remove on scroll increase and decrease behaviour