# hide input type number arrow in tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

I can't do it even though I've tried many ways:
show code:

```html
<div className="bg-transparent pl-3 text-lg w-18  outline-none focus:outline-none hover:outline-none appearance-none hover:appearance-none focus:appearance-none  font-semibold">
```

Comment: Tailwind don't have i guess BTW you can do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823182/material-ui-remove-up-down-arrow-dials-from-textview/50824080#50824080 this

Answer (score 2):

if anyone is still looking for this, the solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71297126/15199227

> In your global.css you have to add:

```
@layer base {
  input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
  input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```